# Teaching myself python

Tags: python, coding-style, computer-science

```
x=0
y = raw_input("""Up to what number would you like to locate primes?: """)
for i in range(int(y)):
x = x + 1
if x%2 and x%3 and x%5 and x%7:
print x, '--> PRIME'
elif x==2 or x==3 or x==5 or x==7:
print x, '--> PRIME'
elif x==1:
print x
else:
print x
```

I've been on break for the last week and a half and I thought I would spend my time learning Python. I wrote this little script earlier tonight that simply prints out a list of integers within a user specified range and identifies which of them are prime. What I want to do but can't seem to find any documentation on is to have the script count the occurrences of the primes and echo a "There were (blank) number of primes within your specified interval." I have no idea where to look for that sort of thing. I don't want an answer but I would like someone to point me in the direction I need to be going in.

As always, 
Thanks.

P.S. This does work, I just want to make it 'better'.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Right now this *doesn't* work- make sure when you post your code that you keep the indentation consistent with how you're running it! (It makes a huge difference in Python)

Comment: Incidentally, you could change `for i in range(int(y))` to `for x in range(int(y))` and get rid of the `x=0` and `x = x + 1` lines.

Comment: `print '\n'.join(str(x) for x in xrange(2,y) if all(x % n for n in xrange(2,x)))`

Comment: or, for count, `print sum(all(x%n for n in xrange(2,x)) for x in xrange(2,y))`

Answer (score 1):

I feel compelled to point out that your code works as long as you enter a number less than 11^2 = 121 (it would mistakenly identify 121 as prime).

The way you've written it is OK, but it doesn't really take advantage of the stronger features of Python. Let's look at the code:

```
x=0
y = raw_input("""Up to what number would you like to locate primes?: """)
for i in range(int(y)):
    x = x + 1
    if x%2 and x%3 and x%5 and x%7:
        print x, '--> PRIME'
    elif x==2 or x==3 or x==5 or x==7:
        print x, '--> PRIME'
    elif x==1:
        print x
    else:
        print x
```

In Python, `for i in range(int(y))` will set `i` to 0, 1, 2, ..., y-1. So, you don't need a *separate* `x` variable to keep track of the value:

```
y = raw_input("""Up to what number would you like to locate primes?: """)
for x in range(int(y)):
    if x%2 and x%3 and x%5 and x%7:
        print x, '--> PRIME'
```

In Python, you can use `in` to quickly test equality against several choices (a special case of testing container membership), so `x==2 or x==3 or x==5 or x==7` can be rewritten as `x in (2, 3, 5, 7)`.

Now, if you want to count the number of primes, let's add a counter:

```
num_primes = 0
y = raw_input("""Up to what number would you like to locate primes?: """)
for x in range(int(y)):
    if x == 1:
        # 1 actually passes the modulo tests and would be considered prime in the original code
        print x
    elif (x%2 and x%3 and x%5 and x%7) or x in (2, 3, 5, 7):
        num_primes += 1 # this increments num_primes by 1
        print x, '--> PRIME'
    else:
        print x
```

And finally print it out with a nice formatted message:

```
print 'There are {} primes between 0 and {}'.format(num_primes, y)
```

Ta-da!

Answer (score 0):

The general way in which people determine whether an integer is a prime is by looping through each integer from 1 to `n` (where `n` is the integer in question) and counting the factors (remember that `i` is a factor of `n` if `n % i == 0`). Of course, they then test whether this count is equal to 2; if it is, `n` is prime - if it isn't `n` is not prime. Something like this (in pseudo-code):

> set count = 0
>   for every i from 1 to n { if (n % i is 0) then increment "count"}
>   if ("count" is 2) then "n" is prime

Obviously there are better approaches but for someone who is just learning this should suffice. In your case, you want to apply this process to each number in an entire range, count how many primes you encounter, and print the result.

And just as a note: make sure to indent your code properly, as one of the comments mentioned (this is a must for Python).

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for. As the P.S. asserts, the code does work (once you indent it properly), as long as you don't give it a number greater than 120; what's missing is the ability to count the number of primes as it goes along and print out the count at the end. You're just giving him a different algorithm to check primeness, which doesn't tell him how to count the number of primes he's found (and the fact that you name a variable `count` makes it confusing).

Comment: Looping is not an especially good way to find primes, but even if you want to approach via looping, there is no reason to loop from 1 to n every time. You can be much more efficient by looping from 2 to int(sqrt(n)), and quit early -- the first evenly-divisible item means, non-prime.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: I did mention that there are better algorithms (one of which you mentioned). The purpose of this post was to illustrate a simple way in which this could be done to a beginner, as opposed to exhibiting the most efficient solution.

Comment: @abarner: Alright I see what you're saying, I'll delete this post if the OP indicates that it is indeed not what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're happy with your algorithm (even though you obviously know it's not really correct); you're just asking what to add to make it keep track of a count of the number of times you print out '--> PRIME' along the way, right?

Well, the description is a clue. You need a counter variable, which starts at 0, and then add 1 to that counter every time you print out '--> PRIME'. Then you can just print that counter at the end:

```
x=0
y = raw_input("""Up to what number would you like to locate primes?: """)
primes = 0
for i in range(int(y)):
  x = x + 1
  if x%2 and x%3 and x%5 and x%7:
    print x, '--> PRIME'
    primes += 1
  elif x==2 or x==3 or x==5 or x==7:
    print x, '--> PRIME'
    primes += 1
  elif x==1:
    print x
  else:
    print x
print 'There were', primes, 'within your specified interval'
```

The next thing you might want to look into is writing a function that does the check for you; then you increment the counter and print the number if the function returns True.

Then you can change your code to filter range(int(y)) into a new list, containing just those values where the function returns true; once you have that, you just have to count how many elements are in the result.

Then you can figure out how to write that as a list comprehension (which is a bit tricky to initially get the hang of, much it makes your code much simpler once you get it).

And then look at turning the original explicit list builder into a generator function, and/or turning the list comprehension into a generator expression. This allows you to print out the results as they come in (by iterating your generator), but it means you can no longer just print the length to get the total count, so you need a different solution.